# Patch multiple id's with one request with React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I have a very basic prototype of app that allows to book a seat. User selects the seat/seats, clicks book, patch request with `available: false` is sent to the fake api (json-server) with React Query, library invalidates the request and immediately shows response from the server.

Database structure looks like this:

```
{
  "hallA": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "seat": 1,
      "available": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "seat": 2,
      "available": true
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "seat": 3,
      "available": false
    }
  ]
}
```

and the logic for selecting, booking seats looks like this:

```
const App = () => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useGetHallLayout("hallA");
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState<
    { id: number; seat: number; available: boolean }[]
  >([]);

  const handleSelect = useCallback(
    (seat: { id: number; seat: number; available: boolean }) => {
      const itemIdx = selected.findIndex((element) => element.id === seat.id);

      if (itemIdx === -1) {
        setSelected((prevState) => [
          ...prevState,
          { id: seat.id, seat: seat.seat, available: !seat.available },
        ]);
      } else {
        setSelected((prevState) =>
          prevState.filter((element) => element.id !== seat.id)
        );
      }
    },
    [selected]
  );

  const takeSeat = useTakeSeat({
    onSuccess: () => {
      useGetHallLayout.invalidate();
    },
  });

  const sendRequest = useCallback(() => {
    selected.forEach((item) =>
      takeSeat.mutateAsync({ id: item.id, hall: "hallA" })
    );
    setSelected([]);
  }, [selected, takeSeat]);

  return (
    <>
      {!isLoading && (
        <ConcertHall
          layout={data}
          onSeatSelect={handleSelect}
          activeSeats={selected}
        />
      )}
      <button disabled={isLoading} onClick={sendRequest}>
        Take selected
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Queries look like this:

```
export const useGetHallLayout = (hall: string) => {
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(["hall"], () =>
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/${hall}`).then((res) => res.data)
  );
  return { data, isLoading };
};

export const useTakeSeat = (options?: UseMutationOptions<unknown, any, any>) =>
  useMutation(
    (data: { hall: string; id: number }) =>
      axios.patch(`http://localhost:3000/${data.hall}/${data.id}`, {
        available: false,
      }),
    {
      ...options,
    }
  );

useGetHallLayout.invalidate = () => {
  return queryClient.invalidateQueries("hall");
};
```

The problem of the above code is that I perform very expensive operation of updating each id in a for each loop (to available: false) and query invalidates it after each change not once all of them are updated.

The question is: is there any better way to do this taking into account the limitations of json-server? Any batch update instead of sending request to each and every id seperately? Maybe some changes in a logic?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly make one mutation that fires of multiple requests, and returns the result with `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled`. Something like:

```
useMutation((seats) => {
  return Promise.allSettled(seats.map((seat) => axios.patch(...))
})
```

then, you would have one "lifecycle" (loading / error / success) for all queries together, and `onSuccess` will only be called once.

Another gotcha I'm seeing is that you'd really want the `hall` string to be part of the query key:

```
- useQuery(["hall"], () =>
+ useQuery(["hall", hall], () =>
```